# Ghostscript prints question mark when converting digitally signed PDF to image

Tags: ghostscript

Ghostscript 9.0 doesn't support validation of the digital signatures in PDF document when doing PDF to image conversion. Instead, there's a question mark on the digital signature, and Ghostscript reports *"Sig is not yet implemented"*. I'm thinking to  modify the source code to get rid of the question mark, but I don't have any ideas to where I should modify in thesource code. Could any one give the hints for that?  Any response will be appreciated highly, thanks.

Comment: tony: We can see this is the first question you asked @stackoverflow... But if you put a bit more care and accuracy into your future questions, it increases your chance to get helpful answers, and it spares other people extra effort to edit away your typos...

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tested the very latest release (which is v9.02)? If so, have you also tested the current 'HEAD' revision of their source code?

If your problem persists with these versions, the preparatory thing to start with is to download the (current, which is v9.02) Ghostscript source code [from here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180818152100/http://downloads.ghostscript.com:80/public) or even check it out from their [Git repository](https://git.ghostscript.com/).

What you are trying to do can only be located in one of the following two modules of the Ghostscript source code:

- the (PDF) interpreter
- the (image) output devices

So I would *first* recursively `grep` the sources for *"not yet implemented"* or similar expressions, taking into account that there may even be line breaks within the string. (***I doubt the quote you gave in your initial version of the question is accurate, because it contained at least one typo.)

If I didn't find anything in the first step, I'd get into touch with the Ghostscript developers themselves. They usually hang around in [IRC on Freenode, channel `#ghostscript`](http://http://git.ghostscript.com/ghostpdl/gs/).

Comment: I've just tested the latest version which is v9.02, the test result is same as I narrated previously but without the report of "Sig is not yet implemented". For the suggestion, could you give more detail into the source code of ghostscript as to switch off the question mark of digital signature's appearance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @chio tony: Can you provide a link to a sample PDF with such a signature that turns into question mark when converted to an image file by Ghostscript? I tested with various signatures and GS 9.02 to convert to TIFF, and all conversions were OK, with same appearance as the PDF in Acrobat viewers... Maybe *my* signatures were made with a different method from yours?

Comment: I've uploaded a file with some signatures embedded for your test at http://www.freefilehosting.net/test_93.  Actually, the conversion of PDF to image for my test is programmed using the gswin32.dll instead of invoking to the executable fo gswinc.exe, and the output image is selected to jpeg format.